# How can I stop pop-ups from resetting the scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I have frankensteined a masonry code and a popup code together. Here's what I got.

CSS:

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count:3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: .25em;
  -moz-column-gap: .25em;
  column-gap: .25em;
   margin: .25em;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: .25em;
    -webkit-column-gap: .25em;
    column-gap: .25em;
    font-size: .85em;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 .25em;
    width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition:1s ease all;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item img{max-width:100%;
    transition:.5px;}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

/*popup*/


.button {
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
      filter: grayscale(.5);
      transition: grayscale 0.5s;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: auto;
  overflow: none;
  text-align:center;
}

.popup .content img {
  max-height: 500px;
  margin:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="item">
        <a class="button" href="#popup9"><img src="/img.jpg"></a></div>
        <div id="popup9" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
                 <img src="/img.jpg">
             <p>This is text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code works as expected, except closing the popup resets the scroll to the top of the page. How can I stop that from happening?

I know at least part of the problem is the # in `<a class="close" href="#">`, and that most answers involve using `event.preventDefault()`,but every form of this code I could find did not work, even after changing stuff around to reference the names in my code, and I don't know enough about Javascript to modify it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment part of a URL (i.e. the `#` character and anything that comes after it) exists specifically for the purpose of linking to specific parts of the webpage, including the beginning of the document. Using it to drive any display logic is probably not a good design pattern.

If you are open to the idea of using JavaScript and you're not looking for a CSS-only solution, the simplest way to implement a toggleable popup would be to toggle the `hidden` attribute on the overlay div. Make sure the attribute is present by default.

```html
        <div class="item">
            <button onClick="document.getElementById('popup9').removeAttribute('hidden')">
                <img src="/img.jpg">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="popup9" class="overlay" hidden>
            <div class="popup">
                <button onClick="document.getElementById('popup9').setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden')">&times;</button>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="/img.jpg">
                    <p>This is text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Since you're not linking to anywhere, use buttons instead of anchors. Apply CSS styling to make the buttons appear as text.

Setting the `hidden` attribute causes the browser to change the `display` property of the popup to `none`. This prevents the popup from transitioning between opacity values. To preserve the transitions, make sure the popup is always displayed, just transparent and unclickable by default:

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
.overlay[hidden] {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Using the `hidden` attribute also ensures that the popup works correctly when CSS styling is disabled, which is important for accessibility reasons. The popup content becomes invisible to screen readers and doesn't distract the user.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was kinda worried when adding the new code gave the non-popup images this gray background, but changing `.button` to `button` in the CSS let me style it away. Thanks!